# Store Canvas image filename and/or location path to database whilst saving?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a canvas image on my page with a Save button that saves down a `PNG` image file.

```
function save() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
   var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST", 
   url: "canvas_ajax_upload_post.php", 
      data: { img: dataURL }      
   }).done(function(msg){ 
      alert(msg); 
   });
}
```

The `canvas_ajax_upload_post.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
$img = $_POST['img'];
if (strpos($img, 'data:image/png;base64') === 0) {
   $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
   $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
   $data = base64_decode($img);
   $file = 'uploads/img'.date("YmdHis").'.png';
   if (file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
      echo "The canvas was saved as $file.";
   } else {
      echo 'The canvas could not be saved.';
   }   
}
?>
```

This works fine, images get saved to the uploads folder on my server. What I have been trying to do is store the filename in my SQL database. I have a hidden form field on my main page that I would like to pass the filename or filepath to after the image has been saved, but I cannot figure out how.

I have tried embedding `JavaScript` code in the `PHP` file, but it just treats it as a text string and includes it in the alert popup.  Essentially what I am trying to do is use the `$file` variable from the php file in `JavaScript` code.

```
 E.g. document.getElementById("hidden_form_field").value = $file;
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you already have code to execute a SQL query?

Comment: You're already sending `data: { img: dataURL } ` so make that `data: { img: dataURL, filename: fileName }` and then make your PHP script save both in their respectively appropriate way. Also, on a different note: _validate that image_ because I can send you a file that starts as `data:image/png;base64<?php letsExploitSomething();` and your code, or dependency code, or even php itself, might very well try to execute that at some point. Get the data from the post, validate it is what it should be (does `gd` agree that it's a real image after decoding, for instance?), and then only write if safe

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the filename in the data object:

```
function save() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('drawing');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "canvas_ajax_upload_post.php", 
        data: { 
            img: dataURL,
            filename: document.getElementById("hidden_form_field").value
        }      
    }).done(function(msg){ 
        alert(msg); 
    });
}
```

Then retrieve the "filename" variable by getting $_POST["filename"]:

```
<?php
$img =        $_POST['img'];
$filename =   $_POST['filename'];
if (strpos($img, 'data:image/png;base64') === 0) {
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = 'uploads/img'.date("YmdHis").'.png';
    if (file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
        echo "The canvas was saved as $file.";
    } else {
        echo 'The canvas could not be saved.';
    }   
    // DO SOME SQL QUERY W/ $filename variable
    // SQL CODE HERE
}
?>
```

You'll need include your SQL query code to use the $filename variable. I didn't see that code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand from your question, you're trying to get the value of $file *back* form php.
You can return the value via the msg variable (which is what php `echo`s) in your `$.ajax.done` function.
For example:

```
function(msg){
    alert(msg);
    if(msg.search("The canvas was saved as")!=-1){//was saved
        document.getElementById("hidden_field").value=msg.slice(23);//assuming string "The canvas was saved as $file."
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well, as did all the other answers. Thank you all. So many options :-)